# Сделать цикл. Геометрическая прогрессия?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день как сделать циклом 
5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320

Comment: Что именно вам нужно сделать? Подсчитать сумму n элементов прогрессии? Или вычислить n-ный элемент прогресии? И что вы уже сделали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```js
var startNumber = 5;
var multiplier = 2;
var quantity = 7;
var i = 0;
    
while (i < quantity) {
    console.log(startNumber);
    startNumber *= multiplier;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Ответ хороший и правильный, но увы, так вы автору не дали возможность ни объяснить что конкретно ему нужно, ни показать что он уже сделал. Так что его вопрос, по сути, не полный, а также несколько не соответствует правилам сообщества.